# So this is the code: But it never considers the first string i write? it doesnt count it even if it ends whith a just the first word

Tags: java

But it never considers the first string i write? it doesnt count it even if it ends whith a just the first word.

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("type some words and when youre finished type exit. (SENTINEL):");
String word=scan.nextLine();
int count=0;
int end = 0;
while(!word.equals("exit")){
    count++;
    System.out.println("type some words and when youre finished type exit. (SENTINEL):");
    word=scan.nextLine();
    if(word.endsWith("a")){        
        end++;              
    }
}
System.out.println("You typed "+count+" words");
System.out.println(end+" of them ends with the letter  a");
```

Comment: Please format your code and rephrase your problem, your question is very hard to read,

Comment: This question already has a correct answer, but I would like to take the opportunity to suggest that this is a perfect situation to use a debugger to figure out why the code doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the second `word = scan.nextLine();` to the end of your loop.

Also, you may not print all the time your prompt in the loop.

```
while (!word.equals("exit")) {
    count++;

    if (word.endsWith("a")) {        
        end++;              
    }
    word=scan.nextLine();
}
```